# visual basic erasing a graphic when moving it to a different point on the screen

Tags: vb.net

How do I erase a graphic as it is moving along the screen? As my code is now it draws the shape on screen multiple times and doesn't ever erase them so it ends up looking like the attached picture.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ero7O.png)

I'm trying to make a game where you shoot a ball from a cannon but I'm having trouble getting the ball to move smoothly and without the ball being on screen multiple places at the same time.

All of the code used:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim BMP As New Bitmap(6000, 6000)

Dim ball As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BMP)
Dim Map As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BMP)
Dim BallSpeedY, BallSpeedX As Integer
Dim BallLoc As Point

Dim Start As Boolean = False



Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

    'Size of the picturebox that is being drawn on
    PictureBox1.Width = Me.Width
    PictureBox1.Height = Me.Height - 24

End Sub


Private Sub StartToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartToolStripMenuItem.Click

    If Start = False Then

        'Resets ball for testing
        BallLoc.X = 800
        BallLoc.Y = 300
        BallSpeedY = 0

        'Starts the timers
        Gametime.Start()
        Gravity.Start()
        MovementY.Start()
        MovementX.Start()

        Start = True

    ElseIf Start = True Then

        Dim ballloc As New Point(800, 300)

        Start = False

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub NewMapToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewMapToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Map.Clear(Color.White)

    Randomize()

        ' Draws map
        Dim firstpt As New Point(0, Me.Height * 0.7)
        Dim pt2 As New Point(Me.Width * 0.2, Me.Height * (((70 - 30 + 1) * Rnd() + 30) / 100))
        Dim pt3 As New Point(Me.Width * 0.4, Me.Height * (((70 - 30 + 1) * Rnd() + 30) / 100))
        Dim pt4 As New Point(Me.Width * 0.6, Me.Height * (((70 - 30 + 1) * Rnd() + 30) / 100))
        Dim pt5 As New Point(Me.Width * 0.8, Me.Height * (((70 - 30 + 1) * Rnd() + 30) / 100))
        Dim lastpt As New Point(Me.Width, Me.Height * 0.7)
        Dim curvepoints As Point() = {firstpt, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, lastpt}
        Map.DrawCurve(Pens.Red, curvepoints)

    PictureBox1.Image = BMP


End Sub

Private Sub Gametime_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Gametime.Tick



End Sub

Private Sub MovementY_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MovementY.Tick

    ' Draws the ball
    ball.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, BallLoc.X, BallLoc.Y, 20, 20)
    ball.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, BallLoc.X, BallLoc.Y, 20, 20)

    ' Accelerated speed
    BallSpeedY = BallSpeedY - 1

    ' Updates position
    BallLoc = New Point(BallLoc.X + BallSpeedX, BallLoc.Y - BallSpeedY)

    ' Redraws image
    PictureBox1.Image = BMP


End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're drawing on a bitmap and setting that to your PictureBox image. Try this...

In your tick event, draw everything directly on the PictureBox Graphics object and refresh the PictureBox. The points are saved as Static variables so as the ball is moving, the same map is generated behind it and whenever you choose new map, it will generate new points and redraw the map.

Basically the concept is to calculate different object movements and then draw everything in one place making sure to draw it in layers: background, next foreground object, etc.

```
Private Sub NewMapToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewMapToolStripMenuItem.Click
    DrawGame(True, True) 
    'Or if you just want a new map and not the ball use: DrawGame(True, False) 
End Sub
Private Sub MovementY_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MovementY.Tick
    DrawGame(False, True)
End Sub

Private Sub DrawGame(refreshMap As Boolean, drawBall As Boolean)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image)
    Static firstpt As Point
    Static pt2 As Point
    Static pt3 As Point
    Static pt4 As Point
    Static pt5 As Point
    Static lastpt As Point

    g.Clear(Color.White)

    If refreshMap Then
        Randomize()
        ' Generate new points
        firstpt = New Point(0, Me.Height * 0.7)
        pt2 = New Point(Me.Width * 0.2, Me.Height * (((70 - 30 + 1) * Rnd() + 30) / 100))
        pt3 = New Point(Me.Width * 0.4, Me.Height * (((70 - 30 + 1) * Rnd() + 30) / 100))
        pt4 = New Point(Me.Width * 0.6, Me.Height * (((70 - 30 + 1) * Rnd() + 30) / 100))
        pt5 = New Point(Me.Width * 0.8, Me.Height * (((70 - 30 + 1) * Rnd() + 30) / 100))
        lastpt = New Point(Me.Width, Me.Height * 0.7)
    End If

    Dim curvepoints As Point() = {firstpt, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, lastpt}
    g.DrawCurve(Pens.Red, curvepoints)

    If drawBall Then
        ' Draws the ball
        g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, BallLoc.X, BallLoc.Y, 20, 20)
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, BallLoc.X, BallLoc.Y, 20, 20)

        ' Accelerated speed
        BallSpeedY = BallSpeedY - 1

        ' Updates position
        BallLoc = New Point(BallLoc.X + BallSpeedX, BallLoc.Y - BallSpeedY)

    End If

    PictureBox1.Refresh()

End Sub
```

And then you don't need this:

```
Dim BMP As New Bitmap(6000, 6000)

Dim ball As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BMP)
Dim Map As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BMP)
```